# Trouble in sending Email through Google's SMTP Server

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am getting an Authentication Exception when I try to send email using Google's SMTP.

My Source Code(very similar to another answer):

```
public static void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String content) {


    String from = "email@gmail.com";
    final String username = "email@gmail.com";
    final String password = "password";


    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    // Get the Session object.
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject(subject);

        // Now set the actual message
        message.setText(content);

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        LOGGER.info("MessagingException in sendEmail:",e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Exception that I am getting is:

```
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: a.b.c.d <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?something cryptic> Please log in via your web browser and then try again. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:826) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:761) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:685) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01
```

Following the instructions, I have allowed less secure apps from https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

But I am still getting the same error. What can be done to resolve this?
I know the password is correct because I am getting a suspicious signin email on google account.